# Windows 8 - Fiddler won't show filtered requests

Tags: filtering, fiddler

I recently upgraded to Windows 8, and now I can't seem to get Fiddler to inspect my localhost requests.

I have followed the instructions for Windows 8 and set the loopback exemptions and installed the certificate.

I am now trying to use a filter for "Show only the following hosts".

If I leave the dropdown set to - No Host Filter -, I can see my localhost requests just fine in Fiddler.

However, if I change that to "Show only the following hosts" and add localhost/mywebapp, then click the "Changes not yet saved" to apply, none of my requests show up.

If I add an external website (eg www.mywebapp.com) as a filtered item, I can see that just fine as well.  It appears to only be localhost items that I can't filter for.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Note: I'm using Chrome and Firefox and neither work.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the "Capture Traffic" flag was off, which is really strange because why was it capturing traffic without the filter set to on??

Anyways, it's working now.

Comment: `Capture traffic` concerns whether Fiddler is registered as the system proxy. If you've manually pointed another browser at Fiddler, the setting is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `localhost/mywebapp` isn't a host; `localhost` is a host. `/mywebapp` is a path, and if you put it in where a host is expected, it's not going to work.